# How to create an array in recursive function in java

Tags: java, arrays, swing, recursion

I have a recursive method that prints out the values in command line. I need to create a temp array with the result an display it using Swing. how do I create the array and store the values each time it loops ?

```
static void listSnapshots(VirtualMachine vm)
    {
        if(vm == null)
     {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please make sure you selected existing vm");
        return;
     }

    VirtualMachineSnapshotInfo snapInfo = vm.getSnapshot();
    VirtualMachineSnapshotTree[] snapTree = snapInfo.getRootSnapshotList();
    printSnapshots(snapTree);
}

static void printSnapshots(VirtualMachineSnapshotTree[] snapTree)
{
    VirtualMachineSnapshotTree node;
    VirtualMachineSnapshotTree[] childTree;

    for(int i=0; snapTree!=null && i < snapTree.length; i++)
    {
        node = snapTree[i];
        System.out.println("Snapshot name: " + node.getName());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Snapshot name: " + node.getName());
        childTree = node.getChildSnapshotList();

        if(childTree != null)
        {

            printSnapshots(childTree);
        }
    }//end of for
```

so instead of JOptionPane I have only onew window with the list of names and can reuse later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A general tactic for building something recursively is to use a [Collecting Parameter](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CollectingParameter).

This can be applied in your case by:

```
static List<String> listSnapshotNames(VirtualMachineSnapshotTree[] snapTree) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    collectSnapshots(snapTree, result);
    return result;
}

static void collectSnapshots(VirtualMachineSnapshotTree[] snapTree, List<String> names)
{
    VirtualMachineSnapshotTree node;
    VirtualMachineSnapshotTree[] childTree;

    for(int i=0; snapTree!=null && i < snapTree.length; i++)
    {
        node = snapTree[i];
        names.add(node.getName());
        childTree = node.getChildSnapshotList();

        if(childTree != null)
        {

            collectSnapshots(childTree, names);
        }
    }//end of for
}
```

Of course, if you really want it in an array, you can convert it afterwards:

```
static String[] getSnapshotNames(VirtualMachineSnapshotTree[] snapTree) {
    List<String> result = listSnapshotNames(snapTree);
    return result.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

With an unknown size, arrays are painful, so a `List` works better for this.